# Blazor server : Struggling to add policy to Google authentication to restrict access to my account only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, google-oauth, blazor-server-side

After successfully making my app authenticate my app with Google, I am trying to add a policy which will only restrict access to my google account.

I used this tutorial to get google authentication working : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4G0kqIG1_0

and I refered to this stack overflow question to add my policy:

[ASP.NET Core authentication with Google only for a specific account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670587/asp-net-core-authentication-with-google-only-for-a-specific-account)

The answer to this question didn't seem to work out for me, my attempt to get the claim returns a null value and I don't know why.

below is the relevant code on Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
                .AddCookie(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Cookie.Name = "GoogleAuth";
                    opt.LoginPath = "/auth/google-login";
                })
                .AddGoogle(opt =>
                {
                    opt.ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID");
                    opt.ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET");
                    opt.Scope.Add("openid");
                    opt.Scope.Add("profile");
                    opt.Scope.Add("email");
                    opt.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                    {
                        string picture = context.User.GetProperty("picture").GetString();
                        string name = context.User.GetProperty("name").GetString();
                        string given_name = context.User.GetProperty("given_name").GetString();

                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", picture));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("name", name));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("given_name", given_name));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });

services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("MeOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    {
                        // returns a null value
                        var name = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

                        /*
                         *  I want to add some logic to only give access to my Google account
                         */
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: You can use `opt.ClaimActions.Map*` methods instead of manually intercepting `OnCreatingTicket` event and adding claims manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict access by account id or email claim (or any other claim, for that matter).

Create a policy and require a specific claim value. Here I'm using [a `FallbackPolicy`](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/) which ensures all endpoints are protected with this policy unless specified otherwise.

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
            GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        )
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Email, "my.email@gmail.com")
        .Build()
);
```

It might be useful to make this configurable. Add this to `appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "AuthorizedEmails": [
    "my.email@gmail.com",
    "someone.else@gmail.com"
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Then we can read this configuration at runtime and apply it:

```cs
var authorizedEmails = Configuration.GetSection("AuthorizedEmails").Get<string[]>();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
            GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        )
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Email, authorizedEmails)
        .Build()
);
```

### Further info

- https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/